# Is it possible to return and display a component using a callback function in setState?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a component when an option is selected from the drop down. I haven't been able to get the "Func" component or any HTML to display but can log stuff to the console.

```
import React from 'react';
import Func from './components/Func'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      option: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.changeFunc = this.changeFunc.bind(this)

  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      option: e.target.value
    }, this.changeFunc);
  }

  changeFunc() {
    return <Func />
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="Func">Choose: </label>
        <select name="options" id="options" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Currency Converter">Currency Converter</option>
          <option value="Win!">Win!</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Isn't really much there but the Func component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Func extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <h2>
        func
      </h2>
    );
  }
}

export default Func;
```

Comment: You're not using `<Func />` inside the JSX of the render method, so why would it render?

Comment: can we see `<Func />`?

Comment: added to post as an edit @RedBaron

Comment: the answers below should work for you @begdev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, keep a toggle flag which becomes true when the action is performed. And you can use that to call the `<Func/>` based on the toggle

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      option: '',
      toggle: false
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.changeFunc = this.changeFunc.bind(this)

  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      option: e.target.value, toggle:!this.state.toggle
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="Func">Choose: </label>
        <select name="options" id="options" onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Currency Converter">Currency Converter</option>
          <option value="Win!">Win!</option>
        </select>
        {this.state.toggle?
         <Func/>
         :null}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: works perfectly!! thank you so much for the help! the part i'm not 100% sure about is "toggle: !this.state.toggle" - does this just mean that toggle will be set to the opposite of its previous value? So if it was false, set it to true and vice verse

Comment: Yes. So u can make use of that toggle to show and hide the `<Func/>` based on the same action

Comment: thank you for this! currently busy with a couple of tasks that require toggling between components, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want it embedded within this component, you can handle it with a conditional in the render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="Func">Choose: </label>
          <select name="options" id="options" onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="Currency Converter">Currency Converter</option>
            <option value="Win!">Win!</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        {
           this.state.option &&
              <YourComponent/>
        }
      </>
    )
  }
```

**If you wish to render it as a separate component** then you can use the `ReactDOM.render()` method directly - Usually this is used for modals or other components that don't need to be embedded within the rest of the app. In which case you can do:

```
changeFunc() {
  // This can be whatever element you want (doesn't have to be body)
  const container = document.getElementById("body");
  ReactDOM.render(<Func/>, container);
}
```